# Why doesn't wysihtml5 plugin work on android browsers?

Tags: android, twitter-bootstrap, wysihtml5

I am working with the wysihtml5 plugin found [here](http://jhollingworth.github.io/bootstrap-wysihtml5/). It works great on all platforms except Android. I cannot get this to work on Android chrome or the default Android browser.  I am guessing this may have to do with the use of iFrames?  Anyone have a solution to this or a better plugin that will work on Android and other platforms? The problem can be seen by going to the previously mentioned link on an Android device.

Thanks